# In MongoDB, I can't drop a view with two consecutive dots in the name

Tags: database, mongodb

I've accidentally named a view : "test..view".
When I try to delete it now I get the following error :
`MongoInvalidArgumentError: Collection names cannot be empty`

I tried running the following command :
`db.getCollection("test..view").drop()`

I also tried to rename it but got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `runCommand` to solve this issue:

```
test> show collections
foo
test..view        [view]
test> db.runCommand({drop: 'test..view'})
{ ns: 'test.test..view', ok: 1 }
test> show collections
foo
```

Ultimately, the error, *"Collection names cannot be empty"*, comes from the client you're using; using Compass and the mongo node module triggered the issue for me. Using my system mongoshell didn't trigger that error.

Comment: This is a valid alternative but `db.getCollection("test..view").drop();` does work in mongosh.

Comment: @jQueeny I'm on the latest version of Mongo Compass (1.40.4 as of right now) & mongosh (v2.0.2) - `db.getCollection("test..view")` works but `db.getCollection("test..view").drop();` does not ‍♂️ However, `db.runCommand({drop: 'test..view'})` worked.

Comment: @aneroid this is interesting. Might be a mongodb version related nuance then as opposed to solely a client tool.  A bit more testing required I think.

Comment: @jQueeny Good point, could be a DB issue too. I'm on MongoDB 7.0.4, on Docker. Using the [official image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/mongo/7.0.4/images/sha256-3ee80b67778b162efb3323c1f1539c573c9928c0540a567ebf5fec15d387327a?context=explore).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```js
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> db.createCollection("bar..baz");
{
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1701808000, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1701808000, 1)
}
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> show collections
bar..baz
other
...
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> db.getCollection("bar..baz").insert({x:1});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> db.getCollection("bar..baz").find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("656f878cc0f674eaa9d2c6d0"), "x" : 1 }
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> db.getCollection("bar..baz").drop();
true
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY> db.getCollection("bar..baz").find();
MongoDB Enterprise rs0:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: Agreed. Although the OP created a view rather than just a plain collection I just tested and it with a view and `drop()` and `find()` work as expected like your answer. Can only assume OP has an error elsewhere or using a client tool other than up-to-date mongosh/compass.